# Deleting and editing list items in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view with two buttons edit and delete.On click of these buttons I either update or delete the items in the list view from my custom adapter.But the problem is if I add a new item to the list my previous changes are discarded and old values are displayed.

> The following is my code for the adapter.

```
public class RoleList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private ArrayList<String> name;
    private ArrayList<String> username;
    private ArrayList<String>  password;
    private ArrayList<String>  role;
    private Activity context;

    public RoleList(Activity context, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> username, ArrayList<String> password, ArrayList<String> role)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.role_list,name);
        this.context = context;
        this.name = name;
        this.username =username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        final View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.role_list, null, true);
        final TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empname);
        final TextView textViewusername = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empusername);
        final TextView textViewPass = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emppassword);
        final TextView textViewRole = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emprole);
        Button edit = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btn_editRole);
        Button delete = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btn_delRole);


        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                name.remove(position);
                username.remove(position);
                password.remove(position);
                role.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("Emp Info", name.get(position) + " " + username.get(position) + " " + password.get(position) + " " + role.get(position));

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.userreg);
                dialog.setTitle("Edit Employee " + name.get(position) + " details");
                final String[] arraySpinner = new String[]{"Manager","Stockist","Cashier","Accountant"};
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                final EditText emp_name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
                final EditText emp_uname = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
                final EditText emp_pw = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
                final Spinner emp_role = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_role);
                final TextView textRole = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_selected_role);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
                emp_role.setAdapter(adapter);
                emp_role.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Role Selected is " + arraySpinner[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        String employee_role = arraySpinner[position];
                        textRole.setText(employee_role);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });


                emp_name.setText(name.get(position));
                emp_uname.setText(username.get(position));
                emp_pw.setText(password.get(position));
                emp_role.setSelection(position);

                Button buttoncancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
                buttoncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                Button  buttonChange = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
                buttonChange.setText("Change");
                buttonChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        textViewName.setText(emp_name.getText().toString());
                        textViewusername.setText(emp_uname.getText().toString());
                        textViewPass.setText(emp_pw.getText().toString());
                        textViewRole.setText(textRole.getText());
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });



                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        textViewName.setText(name.get(position));
        textViewusername.setText(username.get(position));
        textViewPass.setText(password.get(position));
        textViewRole.setText(role.get(position));

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

> The following is the code inside the activity for the Handler class.

```
public void userRolehandler()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                RoleList roleList = new RoleList(UserRegistration.this,employee_name,emp_username,emp_password,employee_role);
                Log.d("ARRAY SIZE", String.valueOf(employee_name.size()));

                userList.setAdapter(roleList);
                roleList.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
    }
```

> Code for constructing the json array.

```
  public void userRoleArray() throws JSONException {
        name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        emp_role = textRole.getText().toString();

        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        jsonobj.put("name",name);
        jsonobj.put("username",username);
        jsonobj.put("password",password);
        jsonobj.put("emp_role",emp_role);

        rolejson.put(counter,jsonobj);
        counter++;
    }
```

> Code for Parsing the array.

```
  public void travRoleArray() throws JSONException {
        response = "{\"result\":" + rolejson.toString() + "}";
        Log.d("RESPONSE",response);
        JSONObject jsonOb = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonOb.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        try
        {
            employee_name.clear();
            emp_username.clear();
            emp_password.clear();
            employee_role.clear();
            for (int i=0; i< result.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jObj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                employee_name.add(i,jObj.getString(KEY_NAME));
                emp_username.add(i, jObj.getString(KEY_UNAME));
                emp_password.add(i, jObj.getString(KEY_PASS));
                employee_role.add(i,jObj.getString(KEY_ROLE));
            }

            for (String name:employee_name)
            {
                Log.i("Name : ",name);

            }
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(UserRegistration.this, "Array Index out of bound exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

> The problem is that the array list gets updated or deleted inside the
>   adapter class but the json array inside the activity still has the old
>   values.I would like to know how can I update the activity from the
>   adapter so that the json array has the updated values?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808319/how-to-send-data-from-list-adapter-to-activity-in-android/36808531#36808531