# How to send data from list adapter to activity in android?

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I have a custom list adapter I would like to pass values from this list adapter to an activity where I set the adapter.
This is my Adapter code.

```
public class RoleList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private ArrayList<String> name;
    private ArrayList<String> username;
    private ArrayList<String>  password;
    private ArrayList<String>  role;
    private Activity context;

    private MyActionCallback callback;
public RoleList(Activity context, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> username, ArrayList<String> password, ArrayList<String> role, MyActionCallback callback)
{
    super(context, R.layout.role_list,name);
    this.context = context;
    this.name = name;
    this.username =username;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;
    this.callback = callback;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        final View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.role_list, null, true);
        final TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empname);
        final TextView textViewusername = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empusername);
        final TextView textViewPass = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emppassword);
        final TextView textViewRole = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emprole);
        Button edit = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btn_editRole);
        Button delete = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btn_delRole);


        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                name.remove(position);
                username.remove(position);
                password.remove(position);
                role.remove(position);
                callback.onActionPerformed(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("Emp Info", name.get(position) + " " + username.get(position) + " " + password.get(position) + " " + role.get(position));

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.userreg);
                dialog.setTitle("Edit Employee " + name.get(position) + " details");
                final String[] arraySpinner = new String[]{"Manager","Stockist","Cashier","Accountant"};
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                final EditText emp_name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
                final EditText emp_uname = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
                final EditText emp_pw = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
                final Spinner emp_role = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_role);
                final TextView textRole = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_selected_role);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
                emp_role.setAdapter(adapter);
                emp_role.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Role Selected is " + arraySpinner[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        String employee_role = arraySpinner[position];
                        textRole.setText(employee_role);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });


                emp_name.setText(name.get(position));
                emp_uname.setText(username.get(position));
                emp_pw.setText(password.get(position));
                emp_role.setSelection(position);

                Button buttoncancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
                buttoncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                Button  buttonChange = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
                buttonChange.setText("Change");
                buttonChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        textViewName.setText(emp_name.getText().toString());
                        textViewusername.setText(emp_uname.getText().toString());
                        textViewPass.setText(emp_pw.getText().toString());
                        textViewRole.setText(textRole.getText());
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });



                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        textViewName.setText(name.get(position));
        textViewusername.setText(username.get(position));
        textViewPass.setText(password.get(position));
        textViewRole.setText(role.get(position));

        return listViewItem;
    }
public interface MyActionCallback{
 void onActionPerformed(int position);
}
   }
```

Log for Null pointer exception.

> 04-23 14:59:16.462 24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   org.bordetuts.com.goldmine, PID: 24919 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   org.bordetuts.com.goldmine.adapter.RoleList$1.onClick(RoleList.java:67)
>   04-23 14:59:16.462 24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444) 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18440) 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028) 04-23
>   14:59:16.462 24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime: 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-23
>   14:59:16.462 24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime: 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-23 14:59:16.462
>   24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
>   04-23 14:59:16.462 24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604) 04-23
>   14:59:16.462 24919-24919/org.bordetuts.com.goldmine E/AndroidRuntime: 
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> I would like to notify the activity that something changed inside the
>   adapter.For eg. Delete was pressed for a certain position. Any
>   suggestions,help or pointers will help.Thank you.

Comment: You can just make a callback, which your activity will implement and call it on a custom action.

Comment: @YuriiTsap thank you can you provide a sample code for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Your Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YourCustomAdapter.MyActionCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // or something like that
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new YourCustomAdapter(this));
}



@Override
public void onActionPerformed(int position) {
    //do here something with your data

}
```

Your adapter :

```
public class YourCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public YourCustomAdapter(
        MyActionCallback actionCallback) {
    mActionCallback = actionCallback;
}

private MyActionCallback mActionCallback;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // your case specific code
    // don't forget to implement view re-using properly,
    // don't inflate view each time
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            name.remove(position);
            username.remove(position);
            password.remove(position);
            role.remove(position);
            //pass position of deleted object or any other thing you want
            mActionCallback.onActionPerformed(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return null;
}

public interface MyActionCallback{
    void onActionPerformed(int position);
}
```

Also you can use the Event Bus, Otto for example, but I think for your case just a custom callback will be enough. It depends.

Comment: public YourCustomAdapter(
        MyActionCallback actionCallback) {
    mActionCallback = actionCallback;
} what does this part of the code do?

Comment: It's the callback, you are passing it to YourCustomAdapter. MainActivity implements MyActionCallback, so after you have performed an action just call this method and the corresponding implementation inside MainActivity will do it's work.

Comment: I get null pointer exception.please check my updated code.In my activity I am just trying to toast the position but the app crashes with a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Looks like a problem inside your code, not with the callback, maybe some wrong initialization, maybe your button is null or something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109982/discussion-between-anup-and-yurii-tsap).